# Generate a link which downloads files from minio in python

Tags: python, minio

I want to use python to store and download file in minio

Below is the code

```
from minio import Minio
import os

def getMinioClient(access, secret):
  
  return Minio(
      endpoint="localhost:9000",
      access_key=access,
      secret_key=secret,
      secure=False,
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
  client = getMinioClient("admin", "Secret_key123")

  try:

    file_name = "myfile.csv"
    bucket = "file_bucket"

    with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
      stat_data = os.stat(file_name)

      # fput_object to upload file
      a = client.fput_object(
            bucket,
            file_name,
            f,
            stat_data.st_size
          )
    print("uploaded")

    # using fget_object to download file
    client.fget_object(bucket, file_name, f"{file_name}_downloaded")

  except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

Only option I know to download file is using `fget_object`

How can I get a link, which upon pasted in url bar get the required file downloaded

Just like link which we get from minio UI, when we click on share of particular file like below

[image]

After clicking on share link, a link is generated which can be used to download that file without even logging in.
[image]

How will I be able to generate the download link from within python code by making connection to minio.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is a method named get_presigned_url that create url for deleting, updating or downloading file. See more at https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/python/API.html#get_presigned_url

For downloading purpose:

```py
url = client.get_presigned_url(
    "GET",
    "my-bucket",
    "my-object",
    expires=timedelta(hours=2),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

at first you must set public policy to your bucket
you can use the following example

```
policy = {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                            "s3:ListBucket",
                            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                        ],
                        "Resource": f"arn:aws:s3:::{self.bucket_name}",
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:GetObject",
                            "s3:PutObject",
                            "s3:DeleteObject",
                            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                        ],
                        "Resource": f"arn:aws:s3:::{self.bucket_name}/*",
                    },
                ],
            }
            client.set_bucket_policy(self.bucket_name, json.dumps(policy))
```

and then you can use from bucket name and file name to generate your file path.

```
client.fput_object(
            bucket_name,
            file_name,
            file.fileno(),
            content_type=file.content_type,
        )

        return f"{self.endpoint}/{bucket_name}/{file_name}"
```